# Sort a string to determine if it is a Anagram or Palindrome in Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, string, sorting

I have a extension names String, with two functions names isAnagramOf and isPalindrome. The first function is supposed to take input as a String, then first it will replace whitespace with no space then sort and compare the string and return a Bool to determine if anagram or not. 
The second function named isPalindrome and will also ignore whitespaces and capitalization, it will then reverse the String and compare to return if it is reversed.

I am new to swift and following a tutorial, but I kept getting these errors no matter how I tried to write it. I have gone through it at least 10 times now and cant get it to work

If anyone can help with this code that would be great, I would also be open to someone showing me another way to write. Perhaps as a array first then to sort the string, I am not sure though.

```
extension String {
  func isAnagramOf(_ s: String) -> Bool {
    let lowerSelf = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    let lowerOther = s.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    return lowerSelf.sorted() == lowerOther.sorted()   // first error:Value of type 'String' has no member 'sorted  
  }

  func isPalindrome() -> Bool {
    let f = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    let s = String(describing: f.reversed())           //second error:Value of type 'String' has no member 'reversed'
    return f == s
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Swift 3** a `String` itself is not a collection, so you have to 
sort or reverse its `characters` view:

```
extension String {
    func isAnagramOf(_ s: String) -> Bool {
        let lowerSelf = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        let lowerOther = s.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        return lowerSelf.characters.sorted() == lowerOther.characters.sorted()
    }

    func isPalindrome() -> Bool {
        let f = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        return f == String(f.characters.reversed())
    }
}
```

A slightly more efficient method to check for a palindrome is

```
extension String {
    func isPalindrome() -> Bool {
        let f = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        return !zip(f.characters, f.characters.reversed()).contains(where: { $0 != $1 })
    }
}
```

because no new `String` is created, and the function "short-circuits",
i.e. returns as soon as a non-match is found.

In **Swift 4** a `String` is collection of its characters, and
the code simplifies to

```
extension String {
    func isAnagramOf(_ s: String) -> Bool {
        let lowerSelf = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        let lowerOther = s.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        return lowerSelf.sorted() == lowerOther.sorted()
    }

    func isPalindrome() -> Bool {
        let f = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        return !zip(f, f.reversed()).contains(where: { $0 != $1 })
    }
}
```

Note also that

```
let f = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

returns a string with all *space* characters removed. If you want
to remove all whitespace (spaces, tabulators, newlines, ...) then use
for example

```
let f = self.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Thanks boss.. all of this was great and helped tremendously. Ive been messing with this thing for a week before finally coming to you guys.